# Why does AngularJS read integer `3` returned by DRF API as `%203`?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is my DRF view which gets called at `/posts/{id}`:

```
class PostViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsActualOwnerDelete,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # new posts from location.
        return Post.objects.filter(location=self.request.user.userextended.location).order_by('-createdAt')

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(actualOwner=self.request.user)

    @list_route(permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def mymostrecent(self, request):
        me = request.user
        try:
            # this gets the most recent post's ID
            post = me.post_mine_set.latest('id')
            did = post.id
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            did = 0
        return Response(did)
```

Now with Angular, when I do to the URL `/posts/mymostrecent`:

```
return $http.get("/api/posts/mymostrecent")
 .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
    $location.url('/posts/ ' + response.data);
 })
```

What gets logged is this:

```
Object {data: 3, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

But the URL becomes this:

```
/posts/%203
```

It still works and shows the correct html page, but how do I get rid of the `%20` in the URL?

This is my `models.py` (probably not needed):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    usersVoted = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="%(class)s_voted_set")
    post = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    actualOwner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_mine_set")
```

Comment: %20 is the URL encoding for a space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this part of code, You are adding a extra space in this line   `$location.url('/posts/ ' + response.data);`

```
return $http.get("/api/posts/mymostrecent")
 .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
    $location.url('/posts/' + response.data); #Removed the space after '/posts/ ' ie. change '/posts/ ' to '/posts/'
 })
```